# Webpack keeps ignoring dead exports

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using the Webpack CLI v5.88.2 trying to generate a standard, ES6 JS file, and my entry file looks like this

```
import { Ajax } from "./modules/ajax/ajax.js";
```

In that module is the following:

```js
export class Ajax{
    static Test() {
        // Some stuff
    }
}
```

My Webpack command looks like this:

```
npx webpack --entry ./src/entry.js --output-filename "entry.min.js"
```

I'm pretty new to this, and i've tried using all sorts of different parameters, including --optimization-used-exports, --optimization-side-effects, and setting library types.

What i'd like is to be able to import that unused exported code into a minified format, but my newly generated file is completely empty, until I actually use that export in my entry file.

It even tells me that there is an orphaned module, so it's found it, just not actually including it in the bundle.

Comment: try `export default class Ajax` and call it like `import Ajax from "./modules/ajax/ajax.js";`

Comment: Webpack's doing the right thing here, though? Don't bundle code you don't use, it'll get added once it actually needs to be (there is no value in having dead code in your bundle, it just makes the bundle bigger than it needs to be)

Comment: Okay so I've tried the default class export and I still just get an empty bundle. My use for this is to create a library that I can use from, but i'd like to separate different modules into their own, well, modules. But by the end, i'd like to just be able to put one JS file in a project

Comment: The feature you're describing is "tree shaking," so if you search for how to disable tree shaking in Webpack, you might find something. But it also may be that once you start making your library and actually using the module, it won't be a dead export any more, so the problem will fix itself when you build the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this, I managed to get what I needed. First off, my Webpack command looks like this now:

```
npx webpack --entry ./src/entry.js --output-filename "entry.min.js" --output-library-name "MyLibrary" --output-library-type var
```

And if I need modules to be imported in, even when not used, I can do this in my entry file:

```
export { Ajax } from "./modules/ajax/ajax.js";
```

And to access this, I can just go

```
MyLibrary.Ajax.Test()
```